# How to make the dropbox upload using gatsby-source-dropbox?

Tags: gatsby, dropbox, gatsby-plugin

I want to use gatsby-source-dropbox and make the UI like dropbox upload form.

Like this
[Dropbox upload form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S22u8.png)

I created the app in the dropbox and generated token.
I configured gatsby.config.js like following, but I can't see anything.

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
plugins: [
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-source-dropbox`,
    options: {
      accessToken: `access-token`,
      extensions: ['.pdf', '.jpg', '.png', '.md'],
      path: '/path/to/folder',
      recursive: false,
      createFolderNodes: false,
    },
  },
]
```

My Environment:

- Windows 10 pro
- VS code editor
- gatsby: "^4.19.0"
- gatsby-source-dropbox: "^0.2.3"

Expected:

I want to see

- gatsby-source-dropbox plugin working
- Build the UI like attached dropbox form

Looking forward to your solution

Thanks